# How to Make Docker Container Only accessable via a Single IP Address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portforwarding

I have a docker-compose file that looks something like the following:

```yaml
version: "3.1"
services:
  app:
    container_name: Apache_web_server
    image: httpd:2.4
    ports:
      - 40:80
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./web-root:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

As it is currently configured, any IP can access the apache web server on port 40. I can change the ports section to this:

```yaml
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:40:80"
```

And it only allows traffic from localhost on port 40 into the container, however if I change the ports section to this:

```yaml
    ports:
      - "192.168.1.24:40:80"
```

And try to turn on the container I get this lovely error:

```
ERROR: for Apache_web_server  Cannot start service app: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint Apache_web_server ([ID]): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 192.168.1.24:40: bind: cannot assign requested address

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint Apache_web_server ([ID]): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 192.168.1.24:40: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

Does anyone know what's going on with this? I want to (in this example) restrict access to the apache web server to only requests from the IP `192.168.1.24`.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/704643/steps-for-limiting-outside-connections-to-docker-container-with-iptables/933803#933803

Comment: Was able to use the code in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/704643/steps-for-limiting-outside-connections-to-docker-container-with-iptables/933803#933803) post provided by @gohm'c

Answer (score 0):

First with the command `ip a | grep -w inet` Check if this address exists in the Linux.

Then check a similar port is open on the desired interface or not, cause problem is binding. Check with the following command whether it exists or not `netstat -nltp`.

Finally, if there is still a problem, create a bridge network in docker-compose and check on it again.